# Svg error in index.html

Tags: svg

When i open svg with inside html without webserver like wamp or xampp it gives error in console **Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.**

How to call svg with javascript from local?

Answer (score 0):

if any thing did ajax calls in your code it is not working in chrome because you are running your file with FTP . if you run your code through webserver it works fine other wise you can use mozilla for local testing. Mozilla supports ajax calls locally

Answer (score -1):

it works fine on svg server for this problem